# Combine two multi-dimensional arrays inner values

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following two objects:

```
var object1  = {
  "user1@yahoo.com": [
    {
      "status": "Unread",
      "message": "Some message 1",
      "senderId": "0063f297-0da6-4c23-9a53-0480c273d177",
      "id": "088b71bc-5b64-4f09-bba4-cf88b3cc598e",
      "time": "2016-05-13T10:30:11.495Z"
    },
    {
      "status": "Unread",
      "message": "Some other message 2",
      "senderId": "0063f297-0da6-4c23-9a53-0480c273d177",
      "id": "39b2850b-d8ac-4d23-9fa6-e7056fb6c030",
      "time": "2016-05-13T10:30:03.310Z"
    }
  ]
};

var object2 = {
  "user1@yahoo.com": [
    {
      "message": "Some message 1",
      "id": "088b71bc-5b64-4f09-bba4-cf88b3cc598e",
      "time": "2016-05-13T10:30:11.495Z"
    },
    {
      "message": "Some other message 2",
      "id": "39b2850b-d8ac-4d23-9fa6-e7056fb6c030",
      "time": "2016-05-13T10:30:03.310Z"
    }
  ],
  "user3@yahoo.com": [
    {
      "message": "Some message 1",
      "id": "088b71bc-5b64-4f09-bba4-cf88b3cc598e",
      "time": "2016-05-13T10:30:11.495Z"
    },
    {
      "message": "Some other message 1",
      "id": "39b2850b-d8ac-4d23-9fa6-e7056fb6c030",
      "time": "2016-05-13T10:30:03.310Z"
    }
  ]
};
```

I need to combine them into a single object that looks something like this:

```
var object3 = {
  "user1@yahoo.com": [
    {
      "status": "Unread",
      "message": "Some message 1",
      "senderId": "0063f297-0da6-4c23-9a53-0480c273d177",
      "id": "088b71bc-5b64-4f09-bba4-cf88b3cc598e",
      "time": "2016-05-13T10:30:11.495Z"
    },
    {
      "status": "Unread",
      "message": "Some other message 2",
      "senderId": "0063f297-0da6-4c23-9a53-0480c273d177",
      "id": "39b2850b-d8ac-4d23-9fa6-e7056fb6c030",
      "time": "2016-05-13T10:30:03.310Z"
    },
    {
      "message": "Some message 1",
      "id": "088b71bc-5b64-4f09-bba4-cf88b3cc598e",
      "time": "2016-05-13T10:30:11.495Z"
    },
    {
      "message": "Some other message 2",
      "id": "39b2850b-d8ac-4d23-9fa6-e7056fb6c030",
      "time": "2016-05-13T10:30:03.310Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

where the email that identifies the group of messages is the same.

Comment: is `user3@yahoo.com` not in the result list because it is not present in *both* `array1` and `array2`?

Comment: yes, combine only user1@yahoo.com nodes

Answer (score 4):

First, get the keys from each object. Then, for each email that is present in both objects, concatenate their lists.

```
var keys1List = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(array1),
    keys2List = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(array2),
    result = {};

keys1List.forEach(function(email) {
    if (keys2List.indexOf(email) > -1) {
        result[email] = array1[email].concat(array2[email]);
    }
});
```

Note that your `array1`, `array2` and `array3` variables actually are objects and not arrays. I would suggest you change their names so that they won't confuse other people (or even you, later) that will read this code.

Comment: Thank you. works like magic. Yeah am renaming them to objects

Answer (score 2):

```
var map = Object.keys(array1).reduce(function( map, email ) {
    map[email] = array1[email];
    if (array2.hasOwnProperty(email)) map[email] = map[email].concat(array2[email]);
    return map;
}, {});
```

Answer (score 1):

combine objects where id = 'user1@yahoo.com':

```
let e = 'user1@yahoo.com';
let a1 = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(object1);
for (let i = 0, j = a1.length; i < a1.length, j < (object2[e].length+1); i++, j++) {
    object1[e][j+1] = object2[e][i];
}
console.log(object1);
```

Answer (score -1):

use underscore

```
_.mapObject(array1,function(val,key){
    return _.union(val,array2[key]);
})
```

Comment: There's no underscore tag in the question, so we should give vanilla-js answers. :)